# A font closer to this one?

Tags: font-identification

I really liked this font and I would like to find out which font it is, and if there is a closer version to it that is free or available on gfont.

[image: font in question]

I've tried a font identification site, but it never identified anything I even tried to cut a single letter of the above to try to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely custom made lettering, possibly based on an existing typeface. Judging by the 'N', a bold variant of [Trajan](https://typekit.com/fonts/trajan-pro-3) was used as the base.

[image]

Comment: ...although the 'G' tells another story.

Comment: That looks really nice and yes I tough some of it was custom made I just wanted something closer to it not exactly like it :) This fits perfectly my needs thanks.